# Unable to get Transaction Details with GetTransactionByID qscc call from another chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

[FABCG-23](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABCG-23),
We recently upgraded our Fabric version from 1.4 to 2.3. In our Chaincode we have business logic to verify a txnId is present in ledger or not. With Fabric 2.3 upgrade we are getting below error. If this is a limitation from added in 2.x to avoid deadlock situation, can you let us know the approaches to get transaction details for a given transaction ID from a chaincode?

**Code**:

```
chainCodeArgs := toChaincodeArgs("GetTransactionByID", stub.GetChannelID(), tid)
     response := stub.InvokeChaincode("qscc", chainCodeArgs, stub.GetChannelID())
```

**Error**:
Rejecting invoke of QSCC from another chaincode because of potential for deadlocks, original invocation for 'testcc'.

Actually, post getting the Transaction data we are verifying whether the MSP submitted is matching with the latest request for the asset. So, we are looking for options at Chaincode rather than client to call qscc and pass the txn details.